# Support vector machines - separating hyperplane question

Tags: language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, svm

From what I've seen, seems like the separation hyperplane must be in the form

***x.w*** + b = 0.

I don't get very well this notation. From what I understand, `x.w` is a inner product, so it's result will be a scalar. How can be it that you can represent a hyperplane by a scalar + b? I'm quite confused with this.

Also, even if it was ***x*** + b = 0, wouldn't it be of a hyperplane that passes right through the origin? From what I understand a separating hyperplane doesn't always pass through the origin!

Comment: remember that here **x** is the *"variable"*, i.e the plane is the set of all points **x** (x is a vector) that satisfy the equation w.x+b=0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is the equation of a (hyper)plane using a point and normal vector.
Think of the plane as the set of points P such that the vector passing from P0 to P is perpendicular to the normal

[image]

Check out these pages for explanation:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Definition_with_a_point_and_a_normal_vector

Answer (score 7):

Imagine a plane in a 3d coordinate system. To describe it, you need a normal vector N of that plane and the distance D of the plane to the origin. For simplicity, assume the normal vector has unit length. Then the equation for that plane is x.N - D = 0.

Explanation: x.N can be visualized as a projection of x on the normal vector N. The result is the length of vector x parallel to N. If this length equals D, the point x is on the plane.

Comment: When you mean the distance of the plane to the origin, you mean the distance of the nearest point of the plane to the origin?

Answer (score 6):

A definition of dot product (wich is an inner product) is

**x** . **y** = |**x**| * |**y**| * cos(a)

Where a is the smallest angle between **x** and **y**.

It is easy to see that **x** . **y** = 0, if a=90 deg (pi rad).

This means that if you have a fixed normal vector **w**, a hyperplane given by:

**x** . **w** = 0

is the set of all points that **x** can "point at" given that **x** has to be orthogonal to **w**.

Now, a hyperplane given by:

**x** . **w** + b = 0

is the set of all points that **x** can "point at" such that **x** . **w** is a constant. As **x** gets longer, |**x**| increases, the angle, a, has to get closer to 90 deg (pi rad), cos(a) decreases, to produce the same constant result. If you however take **x** pointing in the exact opposite direction of **w**, cos(a) = -1 and |**x**| = b (provided that **w** is of unit length).

It turns out that the plane given of this set of points is parallell to **x** . **w** = 0, and shifted in space the distance -b (in the direction of **w**) still given that **w** is of unit length.

This answer is probably not going to help the op, but hopefully someone else will benefit from it.